# Intuitive explanation of Four Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, homological-algebra

In the Short Five Lemma

[image]

where the rows are exact, it is a fact that 
$$\alpha \text{ and }\gamma \text{ injective (surjective) }\implies \beta \text{ injective (surjective)}.$$
I've [heard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_five_lemma) this fact summarized as "if $\beta\left.\right|_A$ is injective (surjective) and $\tilde{\beta}:B/A \to B'/\beta(A)$ is injective (surjective), then $\beta$ is injective (surjective)".

This explanation makes a good deal of sense to me, and I'm looking for a similar explanation for the [four lemma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourLemma.html), and also for questions like this:

[image]

In these cases, we could talk about $B$ containing $A / \ker \psi$, and induced maps on this. Is this the way to go?

Would it be advantageous to consider this from a categorical perspective?

I'm trying to have exercises like the above be not a collection of random facts, but a picture of what's really going on, and explanations like the one above are very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hre's one way of looking at (a) of your posted question:

- $\beta$ injective means that you can replace $B'$ by $B$ (we've identified $B$ with $\beta(B)$), as long as you now interpret $\psi'$ as $\psi'|_{{\rm image}(\alpha)}$. Now there's no point in separating the two occurrences of $B$ nor keeping the map $\beta$; once we identify the two occurrences of $B$, the diagram becomes a bowtie.
- $\alpha$ surjective means you can replace $A$ by $A/\ker\alpha$ (commutativity of the bowtie's left triangle forces $\psi|_{\ker\alpha}=0$). But $A/\ker\alpha \cong A'$, so now there's no point in separating the two occurrences of $A'$ nor keeping the map $\alpha$. Now we basically have the same map twice: $\psi=\psi'$ (technically the maps induced by them via this process, but we'll use the same names) both go from $A'$ to $B$.
- We can replace $B$ by $B/\ker\varphi \cong C$; by exactness; this forces $\psi$ (hence $\psi'$) to be the zero map. Again we identify $B/\ker\varphi$ with $C$; now the diagram is just $A'\longrightarrow C\longrightarrow C'$, where the first map is the zero map.
- By exactness, the second map $\varphi'$ is injective. But by now $\gamma=\varphi'$, so $\gamma$ is injective.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very instructive method. So far they all basically boil down to the explanation I quote above.

Comment: I really like this method of "folding up" the diagram systematically, because it is instructive and elegant. When I try to do something similar in other cases, I'm running into trouble. For instance, I can prove the Short Five Lemma by the ordinary method, but suppose I try to prove it this way. If I'm trying to show injectivity of the middle map, given injectivity of the two outer maps, for instance: suppose I begin by replacing $A'$ by $\operatorname{Im}\alpha$. Now I seem to have messed up the exactness at $B'$, and it doesn't seem to help if I replace $B'$ by $\operatorname{Im}\beta$.

Comment: To you have sort of a general tip, or is this method not generally useful?